# Python directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

So I've been working on a recursive function that loops through my python directory that's only .txt files and the words must be 4 characters long and ignores certain words. Im having trouble being able to get this to print the common word

```
import os
os.listdir("/Users/tylerjones/Downloads")

def walk(dirname, mydict):    
    for name in os.listdir(dirname):
    path = os.path.join(dirname, name)
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        if (path.endswith(".txt")):
            #listifyFile(path,mydict)
            files.append(path)
    else:
        walk(path)
for line in walk:
    line = line.translate(line.maketrans(' ',' ',string.punctuation))
    ignore = ['the','a','if','in','it','of','or','on','and','to','because','ok','']
    line = line.lower()
    for word in line:
        if (line in d) and len(word)==4:
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
            print(d)
        else:
            d[word] = 1
            print(d)
```

Comment: updated the code

Comment: Please have a look at [this checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
and try to edit your question. Up to now your question is kind of vague, making it hard to see what you are doing and where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will search all `.txt` files recursively from `directory_path`

```
import glob
from os.path import normpath

directory_path = 'your_base_dir_path'
for filename in glob.iglob(f'{tests_directory_path}/**/*.txt', recursive=True):
    print(filename)
```